# How to search for appointments in Outlook via VBA/DASL?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to cycle through specific appointments of the current day and display their details in a msgbox.

I found out about DASL filter queries.

However, it only brings up the first appointment it finds. The FindNext method never steps to the next appointment, even though it came from an example I found on the web doing something very similar.

When I set the same DASL filter directly in Outlook, it shows the appointments as expected.

Here is my current sub:

```
Sub GetAppointments()
     Dim sFilter As String
     Dim oExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
     Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
     Dim oAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
     sFilter = "@SQL=" & _
                 "%today(""urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart"")% AND " & _
                 "%today(""urn:schemas:calendar:dtend"")% AND " & _
                 """urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords"" LIKE '%Meeting%'"
     Set oExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
     Set oFolder = oExplorer.CurrentFolder
     Set oAppointment = oFolder.Items.Find(sFilter)
     While TypeName(oAppointment) <> "Nothing"
         MsgBox oAppointment.Subject & vbCr & _
                oAppointment.Start & vbCr & _
                oAppointment.End
         Set oAppointment = oFolder.Items.FindNext
     Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with the same Items collection if you want to get more results:

```
Dim appItems as Outlook.Items
Set appItems = oFolder.Items

Set oAppointment = appItems.Find(sFilter)
     While TypeName(oAppointment) <> "Nothing"
         MsgBox oAppointment.Subject & vbCr & _
                oAppointment.Start & vbCr & _
                oAppointment.End
         Set oAppointment = appItems.FindNext
     Wend
```

When you ask the Items property from a folder, a new Items instance is returned so further `FindNext` calls don't make any sense.

Read more about the `Find`/`FindNext` methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Also you may want to include recurrence occurrences, in that case you need to set up a corresponding property on the `Items` collection:

```
Dim appItems as Outlook.Items
Set appItems = oFolder.Items

appItems.Sort "[Start]"  
appItems.IncludeRecurrences = True

Set oAppointment = appItems.Find(sFilter)
     While TypeName(oAppointment) <> "Nothing"
         MsgBox oAppointment.Subject & vbCr & _
                oAppointment.Start & vbCr & _
                oAppointment.End
         Set oAppointment = appItems.FindNext
     Wend
```

The property returns a Boolean that indicates `True` if the `Items` collection should include recurrence patterns.

This property only has an effect if the `Items` collection contains appointments and is not sorted by any property other than `Start` in ascending order. The default value is `False`. Use this property when you want to retrieve all appointments for a given date, where recurring appointments would not normally appear because they are not associated with any specific date. If you need to sort and filter on appointment items that contain recurring appointments, you must do so in this order: sort the items in ascending order, set `IncludeRecurrences` to `True`, and then filter the items.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I already found a different solution, using restrict instead of find/findnext, that does almost exactly what i want. it sometimes doesn't find all of the appointments. background is, i want to delete these appointments it finds, so i just wrapped the whole thing into a while loop until the restrict returns 0 appointments from the query. not 100% perfect, but it's working for now.